# IOS FacebookSDK apprequests dialog error

Tags: ios, facebook, apprequests

I'm trying to find solution for my problem during two days. And I want to say what I'm sure what I've read all resource where you could give me a links =) 
The problem is. I'm using FacebookSDK 3.1 for iOS. And trying to make apprequests dialog... The code is simple

```
session =[[FBSession alloc]initWithAppID:@"XXXXXXXXXXXX" permissions:nil urlSchemeSuffix:@"xxxxxxxxxxxx" tokenCacheStrategy:nil];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
      [self ShowSessionState:session.state];
      NSLog(@"Acces token data: %@",[session accessToken]);  

      [session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *psession, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
         // NSLog(@"I'm in");

         Facebook * facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"XXXXXXXXXXXX" urlSchemeSuffix:@"xxxxxxxxx" andDelegate:nil];

                 [facebook setAccessToken:FBSession.activeSession.accessToken];
                 [facebook setExpirationDate:FBSession.activeSession.expirationDate];

                 [facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andDelegate:nil];

           }];
```

And all what I see.. just Frame with error - Api Error Code:110; Api Error Description: invalid user Id; Error message: Missing user cookie (to validate session user). 
But the authorization is successful... I have a valid accessToken.. can get my friends or my own FB data.

As I said I've read a lot of resources.... And really the many people have same problem, but I don't found any useful solution for this problem. So help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm found a solution, **maybe it will help somebody else**. Actually it looks like exorcism but works) So the problem is:  If you logged in facebook from safary or Facebook app, webview doesn't save any cookie... so you need make you logging from webview. You can do it with FBConnect package (read more in google). In Facebook.m file you need change code like this:

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];
```

to

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
```

In that case when you will use

```
[facebook authorize:permissions];
```

The login come always in webview and you can use any dialogs like apprequests etc. 
The one more problem)) **Login Dialog doesn't appear?** It's one more Facebook bug)) To solve this you just need make a delay  when call it:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showFBLoginDialog) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

- (void)showFBLoginDialog {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"offline_access",
                            @"publish_actions",
                            @"read_stream",
                            @"user_photos",
                            @"email",
                            @"publish_stream",
                            @"user_likes",
                            @"user_about_me", nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions];    
}
```